# Continue after or die in Php

Tags: php, mysql

I am currently working on a PHP project with MySQL. I have the PHP tag at the top and bottom of the page to start and end the PHP. In between the PHP tags I am opening an echo statement output HTML to the browser. In parts of the page where I need to perform PHP, I end the echo tag and perform a MySQL Query using

```
mysql_query($myQuery) or die("Error");
```

When the MySQL has an error, it stops at that point and the rest of the HTML isn't shown which obviously affects the design of the page.

How can I get the HTML part to continue if the MySQL fails to run.

Comment: Just remove the `or die(...)`. That causes the server to stop processing the page.

Comment: `die()` will exiting the request. Instead using it, you can use some variable to flagged it with boolean value, then write some validation to determine whether to continue the query or not based by that variable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An example of your code would be useful, but in general, the `mysql_query() or die()` pattern is not necessary. If you don't want execution to halt upon the failure of a given query, simply omit the `or die()` part:

```
echo 'Output something';
$res = mysql_query($sql);
if ($res) {
 /* do stuff with the query results */
} else {
  /* output an error if desired... or don't */
  echo 'There was a database error: '.mysql_error();
}
echo 'Output some more stuff';
```

Answer (score 3):

Just replace the die() with some other command. See [this article](http://www.phpfreaks.com/blog/or-die-must-die)

Answer (score 2):

So use `print` instead of `die`?

Comment: A code example would have made this more helpful. Consider adding code examples when possible to add clarity to your answer :)

Answer (score 2):

You put the result of the mysql_query function in a variable and test that.

```
<?php
  $result = mysql_query($query);
  if ($result) then { echo "query was a success"; }
  else { echo "query failed"; }
  //rest of the program continues here...
  echo "on with the show";
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `die` will cause the server to stop processing the remaining page. If you want to display an error and continue loading the page, use:

```
... mysql_query($myQuery) or echo "Error";
```

Answer (score 0):

using 'or die()' is just a quick way of handling errors that really shouldn't happen.

One way that could be better is instead of using echo, put all the output in a variable. when you run anything that could error out, wrap it in an `if` statement (or `try` / `catch` block), and either handle the error gracefully on the same page, or `include()` an error page and `exit`.

I feel that using `die()` in a production app is really not acceptable.